# How do I add a browser tab favicon to my Delphi TMS Web Core Website?

Tags: delphi, icons, favicon, tms-web-core

I want to change the browser tab icon for my website. How do I do this on TMS Web Core websites?

I've added my icon to my project group:

[image: Delphi IDE]

And added it to all the available target platforms (Win32 and Win64) in my project settings:

[image: Delphi IDE Project Settings]

But my icons still aren't displaying:

[image: Browser tabs]

I noticed in my project HTML page, there's `<link $(FavIcon)/>` and `<link href="data:;base64,=" rel="icon"/>` code. So I could just manually change my favicon straight in the HTML, but is that the only way?

Is there a way to do it via Delphi or do I have to manually do it in the HTML file?